# Help understanding queing theory problem

Tags: self-learning, operations-research, queueing-theory

I came across the following queuing theory problem in my book and I have no idea how to solve it. It seems similar to the other ones that I've solved but there is information missing, so I assume that it must have another method.

"There is a small fast food restaurant with 1 server. The server could serve, on average, 30 customers per hour, but he chooses to only receive 20 because he doesn't like long lines. The administration is considering hiring an extra server.

What is the utilization rate of the system?
Average amount of clients in the system?
Average waiting time in the system?

Repeat the calculations, but with 2 servers."

So I don't understand what exactly is it meant by "the server could serve 30 people per hour, but chooses to serve 20". Does this mean that it's a finite queue? Or does it mean that the system is being underutilized?

Is the service rate 20/60?

And also, is "20 customers per hour" the same as the arrival rate? How does having multiple servers changes the outcome?

Comment: The first part means that the average service time is $2$ minutes per customer.  The second part is limiting the length of the queue.  I think it means that if there are $20$ customers in the system ($1$ being served and $19$ in the queue,) then an arriving customer is turned away, but I'm not certain.

Comment: The problem needs to specify an arrival rate. Otherwise, there is no way to compute utilization.

Comment: @prubin That's why I was wondering if the "20 customers per hour" was the arrival rate

Comment: @ThePorcius To me, that is an upper bound on the service rate. If the arrival rate is 20 and the current server has a service rate of 20 (and does not fatigue or take breaks), there would be no reason for the administration to add a second server. So I would expect the arrival rate to exceed 20.